# Replace %20 by a space in a 'url.split' in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I know that this question has been asked more than once here. But the issue I'm facing is a bit different that the one's I checked in previous questions.

I'm retrieving the Category in a variable from the URL in my JS by doing this-

```
$scope.category = url.split("=")[1]
```

This would be a sample URL-

```
sitename/pagename.aspx?Category=Cars
```

I'm facing an issue when there is a space in the category. Say if the URL is like this-

```
sitename/pagename.aspx?Category=Super%20Cars
```

Can you please lemme know how to replace the %20 by a space **along with the url.split.**

Sure this isnt a right one-

```
$scope.category = decodeURIComponent(url.split("=")[1]);
```

Lemme know if you need more info guys. :)

Comment: you mean `decodeURIComponent(url.split("=")[1]);` ?

Comment: yes, typed it wrong :)

Comment: Are you not able to replace directly like var txt = url.replace("%20"," "); ?

Comment: Gosh, I dunno how I missed it..:D:D..Its working ..Thanks man..:D

Comment: Enjoy your coding, you can accept answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by below syntax:

```
 var url = window.location.href;    
 var tempUrl = url.replace(/%20/g," ");
 $scope.category = tempUrl.split("=")[1]
```

Comment: This worked for me..Thanks for pointing it out :)..Well it doesnt work with **g** ...No idea why..It works without it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
url.split('%20').join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `decodeURI` to achieve this.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp

Comment: Tried this..... var url = window.location.href; var decodedurl = decodeURI(url); $scope.category = decodedurl.split("=")[1] .....Isnt working

Answer (score 0):

Use `decodeURI` global function available in javascript. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp

```js
var url="http://www.dummyserver.com/index.php?param1=hello%20world";
var queryParams=url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1).split("&");
for(i=0;i<queryParams.length;i++){
var splitParam = queryParams[i].split("=");
alert("Param: " + splitParam[0] + " :: Value:" + decodeURI(splitParam[1]));
}
```

Comment: Tried this.....    var url = window.location.href;
                       var decodedurl = decodeURI(url);
                       $scope.category = decodedurl.split("=")[1]   .....Isnt working

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the url into string first and then replace %20 with the space and then split,it should work,can try like this:

```
var str = 'sitename/pagename.aspx?Category=Super%20Cars'; 
var res = str.toString();
res = res.replace('%20',' ');
category = decodeURIComponent(res.split("=")[1]);
```